# split dataframe when number is lower than the previous number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a series like this:
`test = pd.Series([2.4,5.6,8.8,25.6,53.6,1.7,5.7,8.9])`

I want to split it into two series at the point where the next number is smaller than the previous one. This only happens once in any series, but it does not happen at a reliable location (could be the 7th place, 4th, etc).

The result should look like this:

```
test1
2.4
5.6
8.8
25.6
53.6
```

and

```
test2
1.7
5.7
8.9
```

Comment: By the way, you have a serie and not a dataframe. If you'd really like dataframes you could use `.to_frame()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the position with

```
pos = (test - test.shift(-1)).argmax()
```

Now the series until that is

```
>>> test[: pos + 1]
0     2.4
1     5.6
2     8.8
3    25.6
4    53.6
dtype: float64
```

Similarly, the remainder is

```
>>> test[pos + 1: ]
5    1.7
6    5.7
7    8.9
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I changed argmax to idxmax because apparently it is deprecated

Answer (score 3):

Could zip to a generator and use next. Then we use np.split and map to pd.Series. Should be quick:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test = pd.Series([2.4,5.6,8.8,25.6,53.6,1.7,5.7,8.9])

i = next(ind for ind, v in enumerate(zip(test,test[1:])) if v[0] > v[1])
test1, test2 = map(pd.Series,np.split(test, [i+1]))
```

Or write it in "one-line" like:

```
test1, test2 = map(pd.Series,
                   np.split(test, [next((ind for ind, v in enumerate(zip(test,test[1:])) 
                                         if v[0] > v[1])+1, None)]))
```

---

**Time comparison:**

```
%timeit map(pd.Series,np.split(test, [next((ind for ind, v in enumerate(zip(test,test[1:])) if v[0] > v[1]), None) + 1]))
%timeit (i for _, i in test.groupby(test.diff().lt(0).cumsum()))
%timeit map(pd.Series,np.split(test, [(test - test.shift(-1)).idxmax() + 1]))
```

Results in:

```
#1000 loops, best of 3: 237 µs per loop  <- Anton vbr
#1000 loops, best of 3: 599 µs per loop  <- Scott Boston
#1000 loops, best of 3: 392 µs per loop  <- Ami Tavory
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
for n,g in test.groupby(test.diff().lt(0).cumsum()):
    print(g)
    print("\n")
```

Output:

```
0     2.4
1     5.6
2     8.8
3    25.6
4    53.6
dtype: float64


5    1.7
6    5.7
7    8.9
dtype: float64
```

As @AntonvBR suggests:

```
test1, test2 = (i for _, i in test.groupby(test.diff().lt(0).cumsum()))
```

Comment: I liked this because it is shortest! :) `test1, test2 = (i for _, i in test.groupby(test.diff().lt(0).cumsum()))` would be enough

Comment: Great addition @AntonvBR